# Can we add/create a duplicate field with and without namespace prefix in a same object

Tags: apex, custom-object, namespace, dynamic-forms, lightning-namespace

I have seen this type of scenario in one of the org,
where the same field is present with and without namespace-prefix
I want to know if is it possible, if possible can you please mention how to create this scenario
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create a duplicate field **with** and **without** namespace prefix in the same object. A namespace prefix is a one to 15-character alphanumeric identifier that distinguishes your package and its contents from packages of other developers on the AppExchange. Once a [namespace prefix](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385558&language=en_US&type=1) is created, it cannot be changed or deleted. Therefore, you cannot create a custom field with the same API name as a managed field with a namespace prefix.

However, you may see a scenario where the same field is present with and without a namespace prefix in an org if the org has installed a managed package that contains a field with the same API name as a custom field in the org.

For example, if the org has a custom field called `Distributor_Discount__c` on the Opportunity object, and then installs a managed package that also has a field called `Distributor_Discount__c` on the Opportunity object, the managed field will have a namespace prefix, such as `SBQQ__Distributor_Discount__c`, while the custom field will not. [This can cause confusion and errors, so it is recommended to rename the custom fields to have a different API name than the managed fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382164&type=1).